# css3 translate add more height and width

Tags: html, css, translate-animation

I'm suffering an issue while using css translate as it adds undesired height to the body,
Here's my code:

```
body {width: 1024px; height: 768px;  background: #FFF4B8;}

div.animated {
width: 100px;
height: 100px; 
background: black; 
position: absolute; 
top:100px; 
left:100px; 
-webkit-animation: fadeInUpBig 2s both 1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

and the html:

```
<body>
<div class="animated">
</div>
</body>
```

I tried to use `overflow: hidden` for the body, but it only removes the scrollbars and the extra height still there.

Comment: have you tried changing the position of the animated div to fixed?

Comment: Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137

Comment: yes, I tried using position fixed but nothing changed

Comment: 2000px? Really....that's seems unnecessary. Anyway...can't you just use position values instead of `translate`?

Comment: @Paulie_D I can't use position values because i have lots of elements to be animated, and top property will be specified to each element, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The translate function moves the element on the screen (and perhaps off it) but causes the page to re-render accounting for the movement...hence the scrollbars.

Using a position value (top:-2000px) just moves the element off the page but does not cause a re-render of the page.

[**Position Value Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/AU6qv/)

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top:-2000px;    
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    top:100px;
  }
}
```

[**Translate Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/AU6qv/1/)

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpBig {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, but i already know that top property will work fine, but I have a lot of elements that need the same animation but with different top property so I need something to be general for all animated elements.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to declare different translate values too? Don't see the difference...but if it doesn't work for you then OK.